# yos-social-php5 dynamically set SDK configuration?

Tags: php, yahoo-api

I am using official [Yahoo php sdk](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php5). I want to set configuration variables dynamically. Is there any built-in function for achieving this functionality.

Right now variables are defined statically.

```
define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY', '###');
define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET', '###');
define('OAUTH_DOMAIN', '###');
define('OAUTH_APP_ID', '###');
```